# How do i duplicate/ clone nested array item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, multidimensional-array

I need to duplicate the object with details each separately.
Now onclick setValues duplicates all array with details. I have already tried everything, the result is the same, I must be looking somewhere wrong

```
const [values, setValues]=useState({
  id: 0,
  date: new Date(), 
  address: '',
  recipient: '',
  comment: '',
  details: [{
    category: '',
    comment: '',
    term: new Date(),
    priority: '',
    status: '',
    status_comment: '',
     }
    ]
}
)


const handleDuplicate=() =>{
        let copy = {...values}
        copy.details.forEach((element, index) =>{
           if(copy.details.indexOf(element) === index){
               for(let el of [element]){
                   const newEl = {...el}
                   copy.details.push(el)
                   console.log(newEl)
               }
           }
        });
        setValues({...copy})
}
{values.details.map((value, i) => {
   <TableCell>
   <TextField
    name='priority'
    onChange={e => handleDetailChange(e, i)}
    value={values.details[i].priority}
    disabled={isDisabled}/>
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell>
  <IconButton
   disabled={isDisabled}
   onClick={e => {handleDuplicate(e, i)}}>
  <ContentCopyIcon/>
  </IconButton>
  </TableCell>}
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate more

Comment: create a copy of the object with the values ​​and save it in the state as a new one, but with the same values ​​of the parent

Comment: Don't use forEach and then push elements to the array you are forEaching over.  Use map to create a copy.  Check https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state

Comment: What about Spread and Object.assign()?

Comment: is this `copy.details.push(el)` is suposed to be `copy.details.push(newEl)`.  I agree with the other posters in that the style could be more eloquent, but I don't think that is the cause of your problem.  I certainly have seen very ineloquent javascript work...  I think `details = details.filter( blah ).map( blah2 )` type of code would be a bit easier to understand...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
setValue(prevState=>({...prevState, details:prevState.details.map(x=>{...x})})
```